# Does Quine's relativism only follow if the data of theories is the only source of a theory's justification?

Tags: relativism, quine

Quine saw that any group of theories could have the same pieces of data.

There is a gap between any set of data and the interpretation we have of it.

Quine then felt that in light of this, whether this or that theory/belief were true and correct is relative, since any theory in consideration could contain the same data.

But does this conclusion only follow if it is held that the data of theories is the sole form of justification of any theory?

Comment: The observation does not apply only to *empirical* data, but to any data, including any finite collection of substantiating beliefs, even religious ones, that do not have certain 'meta-fying' properties among them.  Whatever you choose to explain, there will be infinitely many potential theories that explain it.

Comment: @jobermark You are correct. The 'data' in question needn't be limited to empirical data. I'll edit the question.